# Highlight current menu item asp.net using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I want to highlight my current menu item in asp.net with jquery but I don't know why it is not working. Here is my code:

**Site.css:**

```css
#menu {
    background: #292929;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0em 2em;
    line-height: 80px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}
#menu .current_page_item a {
    background: #01A9DC;
    color: #FFF;
}
#menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #01A9DC;
    color: #FFF;
}
#menu a:active {
    background: #01A9DC;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**Site.Master:**

```html
<div id="menu" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.aspx" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Softcare/SoftcareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softcare</a></li>
        <li><a href="Softlearn/SoftlearnHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softlearn</a></li>
        <li><a href="Software/SoftwareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Software</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery (1.7.1) inside `<head>`:**

```js
var path = window.location.pathname;
path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
path = decodeURIComponent(path);

$("menu ul li a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current_page_item');
    }
});
```

I also tried with javascript and it didn't work out well either, i think jquery is the best at doing this job, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to debugg it? Where does it break? There are some great client-side debugging features build in the chrome browser. Just hit f12 and the developer tool will show. Here is a link for further reading about the tool: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: just to be clear, jQuery == javascript !!

Comment: @PeterVR yea...what i mean is javascript without jquery library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the flawless way I have always used jQuery to highlight the current menu item

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vector, this is working fine for most of my pages, but for my homepage, it highlights all my menu items, any idea on how to fix that? Most importantly, i have a sidemenu, and it highlights fine also, but is there a way to highlight the main menu it lives in? for example, for the url Tutor/Timeslots, Tutor is in main menu and Timeslots is a sidemenu item, when i click on Timeslots, it highlights Timeslots but doesn't highlight Tutor in main menu, thanks again